# Understanding polarization of light

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, visible-light

I am very new to electromagnetic waves,so i want to know if what i understand about polarization of light is true or not. I will start from how light waves are produced.

We imagine a charge is sitting in a $3D$ space. So at each point in space,a vector is assigned which depics the electric field's magnitude and direction at those points in space. If the charge starts accelerating,then each of those vectors at the points will start oscillating by changing their direction and magnitude. If the vector is resoluted in the $x,y,z$ components then it is clear that those components of the vector are oscillating. So,what we see as an ideal sinosoidal electromagnetic wave is *the oscillation of a paticular component of the vectors*. I mean,an electromagnetic wave will be formed by the oscillation of $x$ components only and another one with $y$ component only and others with $z$ components only. So i understand electromagnetic waves in this way. Is this correct? If it is wrong,please correct me providing the proper theory.

Comment: The polarization is the direction of the electric field. Whether the oscillation is produced by an oscillating electron, a current loop, or an atomic process isn't relevant.

Comment: [What are photons, EM radiation and EM waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957)